# как сделать canvas полного размера по div?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

мне надо, чтобы `div` в `body` занимал весь экран. и чтобы canvas растянулся по этому `div`. но проблема в том, что canvas таки растягивается, а не принимает нужный размер. то есть я задал квадраты в `96px` например, и если `width` указать `100%`, то будет не `96px`.

```js
let dia = document.getElementById("dia");
let canvas = document.getElementById("diagrams");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "#bcbcbc";
console.log ("width: " + canvas.width + "; height: " + canvas.height);
console.log ("dia width: " + dia.width + "; dia height: " + dia.height);
console.log ("body width: " + document.body.width + "; body height: " + document.body.height);
for ( let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += 96 ) {
    for ( let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 96 ) {
        ctx.rect(x, y, 96, 96);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#dia {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#diagrams {
    clientWidth: 100%;
    clientHeight: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dia">
    <canvas id="diagrams"> 
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let dia = document.getElementById("dia");
let canvas = document.getElementById("diagrams");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
resizeCtxCanvas(ctx);

function resizeCtxCanvas(ctx) {
  const { width, height } = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  ctx.canvas.width = width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  drawCanvas(ctx);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  resizeCtxCanvas(ctx);
});

function drawCanvas(ctx) {
  const canvas = ctx.canvas;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#bcbcbc";
  for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += 96) {
    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 96) {
      ctx.rect(x, y, 96, 96);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#dia {
  height: 100%;
}

#diagrams {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dia">
  <canvas id="diagrams"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю это хороший вариант)